# Android: OpenGL texture without alpha is just white on HTC One x

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have a problem that I see on a HTC One x with Android ICS but not on any other device I tested so far:

All textures that do not have an alpha channel (24 bit png) and for which I do not enable alpha blending are just white on that device. See the code below that I use to draw the textures, m_alpha_blend is false for the textures that do not have an alpha channel:

```
if (m_alpha_blend) {
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture_id);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, m_texture_buffer);

... (drawing)

gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
if (m_alpha_blend) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It's not a problem of the alpha / transparency, but of the texture size. All textures with a side bigger than 1024 pixels get displayed white on that device.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run something like:

```
int max;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &max);
```

On each device, and then downgrade your texture to a smaller size if the device doesn't support your maximum resolution textures.

Comment: I've discovered another problem: I had all textures in the drawable folder, so they got prescaled by BitmapFactory.decodeResource() and could get very large on devices with a high density like the HTC One x. Now, I've put all textures in the drawable-nodpi folder so they do not get prescaled anymore.